# Paypal responding to IPN verification with 500 error

Tags: paypal-ipn

Every once in a while Paypal is returning a 500 error code to my .net applications ipn script.  It is returning that code in the response to the verification request

Here's the error that is logged:

System.Net.WebException
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ASP.ipn_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

The code that Im using for the call is:

```
  endPoint = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

  //Set values for the request back
  req.Method = "POST";
  req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
  string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
  strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
  req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

  //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
  StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
  streamOut.Write(strRequest);
  streamOut.Close();
  StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
  string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
  streamIn.Close();
```

This probably happens about once per day and PayPal doesn't retry the ipn message.  The other 95% of the PayPal ipn transactions are working fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: We're experiencing exactly the same issue at the moment. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help much here.  We didn't change anything and the problem pretty much went away.  We've seen it very sporadically since then....but I do think that (at least usually) the IPN actually does get retried at a later time.